# TStringList - odd behavior

Tags: delphi

Delphi 1 16-bit (yeah it's old, but it works well)

Some sample code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SL: TStringList;
begin

  SL := TStringList.Create;
  SL.Sorted := True;
  SL.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

  SL.AddObject('A', TObject(100));
  SL.AddObject('A', TObject(999));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(LongInt(SL.Objects[0]))); {A}

  SL.Free;

end;
```

I'm using the Object field to store longints (a hack, yes but it gets the job done). Anyway, at line A above I would expect ShowMessage to show 100, instead it shows 999 (even if dupIgnore is set). Am I missing something here? Or should it work this way (I expected the stringlist to ignore the 999)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tested in Delphi 2009 - it shows 100 (and it should show 100 according to the Delphi 2009 documentation about Duplicates and dupIgnore).

Probably it is Delphi 1 bug.

---

**Updated**

@Sertac Akyuz: Yes, that seems to be true. [Google shows](http://members.pcug.org.au/~graydr/delphi/MemLeaks/Memleaks.htm) that old Delphi versions had the following implementation of TStringList.Add and TStringList.AddObject methods:

```
function TStringList.Add(const S: string): integer;
begin
  if not Sorted then
    Result := FCount
  else
    if Find(S, Result) then
      case Duplicates of
        dupIgnore: Exit;
        dupError: Error(SDuplicateString, 0);
      end;
  InsertItem(Result, S);
end;

function TStrings.AddObject(const S: string; AObject: TObject): Integer;
begin
  Result := Add(S);
  PutObject(Result, AObject);
end;
```

The current (Delphi 2009) implementation is:

```
function TStringList.Add(const S: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := AddObject(S, nil);
end;

function TStringList.AddObject(const S: string; AObject: TObject): Integer;
begin
  if not Sorted then
    Result := FCount
  else
    if Find(S, Result) then
      case Duplicates of
        dupIgnore: Exit;
        dupError: Error(@SDuplicateString, 0);
      end;
  InsertItem(Result, S, AObject);
end;
```

See the difference. The old implementation may be viewed as a bug (memory leak, etc) or an undocumented allowed behavior. In any case the current implementation is free from the problem.

Comment: [The Delphi XE documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStringList.AddObject) doesn't say anything about it. It only says that duplicate *strings* are ignored. It says nothing about what happens to the object tied to the duplicate string.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy - dupIgnore blocks the attempts to add duplicate strings (with or without objects) to the sorted list. The index returned does not matter in this case - string is not added to the list.

Comment: Rob is not talking about the string - it sure is not added. He talks about the *object* tied to the dupe string. The docs does not say what happens to the object. With earlier versions of Delphi, while the dupe string is not added, the object tied to it replaces the previous object. It should be considered a design choice instead of a bug, probably a bad one since they changed it (I've seen a post complaining dated 2004, so the behavior probably changed after D7).

Comment: Seeing the source for Add/AddObject makes it clear. Probably not the greatest design choice. I ended up adding a SL.IndexOf('A') call. It fixes the problem, at the expense of more code. Thanks everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 3):

You're not missing anything. That's exactly what happens.

`AddObject` starts by calling `Add`, which returns the index of the new (or existing) element in the list. Then it calls `PutObject` to assign the object value at that index. Behavior with respect to the `Duplicates` property is not specified in the documentation.